# Service server doesn’t get the subscriber objects readings

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote this class for a laser/scan subscriber:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
import time

class laser_sub_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("/kobuki/laser/scan", LaserScan, self.laser_callback)
        self.ctrl_c = False
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdownhook)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)
       

    def shutdownhook(self):
        rospy.loginfo("laser shutdownhook! stopped!")
        self.ctrl_c=True
    
    def laser_callback(self, msg):
        rospy.loginfo("laser_callback")
        self.range= msg.ranges

if __name__=="__main__":
    rospy.init_node("laser_scan_subscriber")
    laserScan_sub_ob = laser_sub_class()
    rospy.spin()
```

and, I wrote this service_server that makes an object of mentioned class:
laser_sub = laser_sub_class()

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Trigger, TriggerResponse
from laser_scan_subscriber import laser_sub_class
import time


def serv_callback(request):
    rospy.loginfo("The Service obstacle_avoidance_service has been called")
    laser_sub = laser_sub_class()
    #time.sleep(0.3)
    
    r = laser_sub.range
    r_min= min(r)
    min_ind = r.index(r_min)

    response = TriggerResponse()
    response.success = True
    response.message = "straight"

    if r_min <0.4:
        response.success = False
        if min_ind<360:
            response.message = "left"
        elif min_ind>360:
            response.message = "right"
        elif min_ind==360:
            if r[0]>r[710]:
                response.message = "right"
            else:
                response.message = "left"
    
    return response


rospy.init_node("obst_avoid_service_server")
rospy.Service("obstacle_avoidance_service", Trigger, serv_callback)
rospy.loginfo("Service /obstacle_avoidance_service Ready")

rospy.spin()
```

When I call this service, I get this:

**‘laser_sub_class’ object has no attribute ‘range’.**

but I've declared in callback of the subscriber class that: **self.range= msg.ranges**

so why the object has no range attribute?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367981/service-server-doesn%E2%80%99t-get-the-subscriber-objects-readings/) by [Morteza70](https://answers.ros.org/users/31125/morteza70/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You only declared it in the callback. Until the callback is called once, it does not exist.
As a subscriber needs a little time to be fully available, and then it needs to receive a message for the callback to be fired, you'll probably simply haven't received any message.

Thus, `self.ranges` doesn't exist the moment you are trying to access it.

I suggest you setup an instance of your `laser_sub_class` in global scope, such that it is instantiated at the beginning of the script and then continuously listening to incoming topics. Not only at the moment of the service call.
And it would also make sense to instantiate `self.ranges` in the constructor and assign it e.g. `None` and check for that in the service call.

Or you could get rid of your `laser_sub_class` all together and use the [`rospy.wait_for_message` function](https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morteza70](https://answers.ros.org/users/31125/morteza70/) on 2020-12-19**:
Thanks,

It worked!